# Laravel-Volley: Unexpected response code 419 when attempting POST method

Tags: php, android, json, laravel-5, android-volley

I am trying to perform a POST request on Laravel and Volley, but the same error has been appearing for some time now. For this example, I'm trying to do so by creating a JSONObject; then trying to receive it on Laravel.

This is my code on Android Studio:

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText name, surname, phone;
Button btn;
String url = "http://192.168.*.*:80/VolleyPost";
RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.post);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtname);
    surname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtsn);
    phone= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtphone);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.post: {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            try {
                object.put("Name", name.getText().toString());
                object.put("Surname", surname.getText().toString());
                object.put("Phone", phone.getText().toString());
                Log.d("Object", "" + object);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JsonObjectRequest jsonrequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, object,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d("Response", ""+response);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e("VOLLEY", ""+error);
                        }
                    });
            jsonrequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            requestQueue.add(jsonrequest);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Then I'm trying to fetch the JSON object on laravel like this:

web.php:

```
Route::post('/VolleyPost', 'PublicController@addPerson');
```

PublicController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Person;

class PublicController extends Controller
{
    public function addPerson(Request $request)
    {
        $person= new Person();

        $person->Name= $request->Name;
        $person->Surname = $request->Surname;
        $person->Phone = $request->Phone;
        $person->save();
    }
}
```

Just in case, this is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'persons';
    public $timestamps=false;
    protected $primary_key='id';
     protected $fillable = ['Name', 'Surname', 'Phone'];

}
```

I've as well added an exception on the VerifyCsrfToken.php:

```
protected $except = [
        //
        'http://dev.com/VolleyPost',
    ];
```

At first I was getting a TimeOutError, which was solved after implementating the last bit of code. Nevertheless, I can't get rid of this error,

> 03-05 20:17:58.989 14139-14178/com.example.umi.volley1 D/Volley:
>   [1174] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ]
>   http://192.168.*.*:80/VolleyPost 0x67692ab4 NORMAL 1>
>   [lifetime=8146], [size=1518], [rc=419], [retryCount=0] 03-05
>   20:17:58.989 14139-14178/com.example.umi.volley1 D/jdwp: sendRequest :
>   Len=0x4E 03-05 20:17:58.989 14139-14178/com.example.umi.volley1
>   D/jdwp: sendRequest : Len=0x4F 03-05 20:17:58.989
>   14139-14178/com.example.umi.volley1 D/jdwp: sendRequest : Len=0x4E
>   03-05 20:17:58.991 14139-14178/com.example.umi.volley1 E/Volley:
>   [1174] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 419 for
>   http://192.168.*.*:80/VolleyPost 03-05 20:17:58.992
>   14139-14178/com.example.umi.volley1 D/jdwp: sendRequest : Len=0x52
>   03-05 20:17:58.995 14139-14178/com.example.umi.volley1 D/jdwp:
>   sendRequest : Len=0x4E 03-05 20:17:58.995
>   14139-14178/com.example.umi.volley1 D/jdwp: sendRequest : Len=0x4E
>   03-05 20:17:58.995 14139-14178/com.example.umi.volley1 D/jdwp:
>   sendRequest : Len=0x4E 03-05 20:17:58.995
>   14139-14178/com.example.umi.volley1 D/jdwp: sendRequest : Len=0x4B
>   03-05 20:17:58.996 14139-14178/com.example.umi.volley1 D/jdwp:
>   sendRequest : Len=0x6C 03-05 20:17:58.999
>   14139-14139/com.example.umi.volley1 D/jdwp: sendRequest : Len=0x52
>   03-05 20:17:59.000 14139-14139/com.example.umi.volley1 D/jdwp:
>   sendRequest : Len=0x57 03-05 20:17:59.000
>   14139-14139/com.example.umi.volley1 D/jdwp: sendRequest : Len=0x47
>   03-05 20:17:59.002 14139-14139/com.example.umi.volley1 D/jdwp:
>   sendRequest : Len=0x49 03-05 20:17:59.002
>   14139-14139/com.example.umi.volley1 D/jdwp: sendRequest : Len=0x49
>   03-05 20:17:59.016 14139-14139/com.example.umi.volley1 E/VOLLEY:
>   com.android.volley.ClientError

in order to make everything work. Am I missing something? Is something wrong with my code? I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to change 'http://dev.com/VolleyPost', for '/VolleyPost' as the value of $except ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below url in the VerifyCsrfToken.php and try.

URL:

```
http://192.168.*.*:80/VolleyPost
```